How to "cluster" the predominant HUEs in an image in PHP
I have a catalog with images where there's a text overlay. The overlay has 3 texts, one of them is colored. The current color is equal for all pages. This results in hues of the text mismatching the underlying photos.
I want to make PHP use the style HTML tag to force each individual page to have a different color in the title, for each page matching the HUE of one of the most predominant colors in the image and then raise the value in HSV to the 100% and set the saturation in HSV to 50%, so I have a "light color" whose HUE matches the image.
Example of 3 original pages
In those images all the titles have the same color (unmatched to the background photo):



Color analysis
At human sight there are some "predominant colors" in any photo you look at. This is the example of how would we see the "most important colors" in the 3 photos above:



Desired result
If in the browser's inspector I pick the "beigeish" in China, the "orangeish" in India and the "greenish" in Costa Rica and I raise the V to 100% and set the S to 50% I get the desired result:



Question
How can I do this programmatically?
Investigation so far
One method of doing this would be:

Use one of the popular image extensions/libraries like ImageMagik or GD to extract the histogram.
The histogram returns a collection of pixels, each with one given RGB and count of number of appearances in the image.
Use the histogram RGB to calculate the HSV model.
Loop over the list of HSVs and look only to the Hue (H) and create a new histogram that accumulates the hues, disregarding S and V. Therefore if our hues are ranged from 0 to 359 and we work only on integers, we'd end up with an array of indexes 0 to 359 with the values being "the number of pixels in the image that have that hue".
Still very nearby hues should be "clustered". If I get "hue 200 => 1000 pixels, hue 201 => 1000 pixels", this is more important than if I get "hue 300 => 1500 pixels and no nearby hues are detected", because from the human point of view, 200 and 201 could be clustered together. This is easy in simple histograms, but this is the difficult part in very complex histograms.
In the clustering, also we need to take care of roll-over. Assuming H has a domain from 0 to 359, then 360 = 0. So hues 358, 359, 0 and 1 could be clustered together.
Sort hue-clusters by pixel-count.
Use the hue of the most- or second-most- or even third-most-full cluster as the base for the final color.

To do the clustering, I feel that maybe I could process the histogram by using the moving-window (AKA sliding-window) technique with a given window size (maybe 20 hues), counting the total number of pixels inside the window, and resulting in a "softened" version of the histogram. Then seek for the relative maximums.
Nevertheless, I feel all this is too cumbersome and I wonder if there's a simpler solution or open source library to achieve what I need in PHP. My internal question is: Is there any open-source graphic library for PHP that I can pass-in the image and it returns me a clustered histogram?
If there's not, what's the best algorithm to "cluster" the predominant hues?

I know my comment may be a kind of out-of-context, but why do you need to do all this effort to only change a single color of text for a pre-defined list of images? I mean, you can make it as an input in your gallery management dashboard :D. However, you can start with this package as a reference https://github.com/thephpleague/color-extractor

Because it's not a "predefined list". An product-manager may change the image suitable for the catalog at any time, they may change the images in batches of 100 or even more at a time and I don't want to add manual processing more than "uploading the images" and the system doing the rest. In the question I don't state that necessarily the image processing is going to be done "on page display". Maybe I cache the data once the image is uploaded and then making the PHP to get the "suitable color" from a database. But "populating the color" should be automatic, not manual.

BTW => the The-Php-League color-extractor sounds great. If I test it and it serves the purpose, I'll let you know!

I wouldn't discard S at step 4, in fact I would only take H where S is relatively high, since H is inaccurate when S is low.

Also, you can sum the bins twice at the end. Maybe once in steps of 30 degrees starting at 0, then again in steps of 30 degrees starting at 15, then you'll reduce edge and binning effects. Just take largest bin of the two passes.

You can try reducing your image to 4-5 colors with ImageMagick and take the one with most pixels https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colors That would be magick YOURIMAGE -colors 5 -unique-colors txt: to get the 5 top colours as text.
